# how to use string as a name of Object(TextBlock)?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have 9 textblock named as "_20" or "_21". I am taking input from textbox and joining them to get the name of required cell. like this:

```
var r = Int32.Parse(row.Text)-1;
var c = Int32.Parse(column.Text)-1;
var cellValue = ('_' + Convert.ToString(r)+Convert.ToString(c));
```

Now when I'm doing `var cell = (TextBlock) MainWindow (cellValue);` to get the specific cell, it is showing error. How should I fix this?

Comment: Instead of having 20 fields of type textbox, use a single array with 20 elements. Then it's easy to find the correct one by using its index in that array: `myTextboxes[17]`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the `FindName` method:

```
var cell = (TextBlock)MainWindow.FindName(cellValue);
```